# multiple answers for the integral of sech(x)?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Let $I= \int\operatorname{sech}x dx$ .

On the one hand when we apply the substitution $u = e^x$ we get equation 1: $I \stackrel{(1)}{=} 2\arctan(e^x)+c$. We could also substitute to $u = \tanh(x)$ and obtain 2: $I \stackrel{(2)}{=} \arcsin(\operatorname{sech}(x))+c$. Or we could substitute $u = \sinh(x)$ which makes 3: $I\stackrel{(3)}{=} \arctan(\sinh(x))+c$. How can we show the equivalence, at least by a constant for each of these results? I'm bewildered by equations 2 and 3 because $\arctan(t)= \arcsin(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}})$, which implies $I=\arcsin(\tanh(x))+c$.

Either I've gone wrong somewhere or every one of these answers is right.

Comment: What are equations 2 and 4?

Comment: sorry, i meant 2 and 3

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function

Comment: You can label equations using `$\stackrel{(1)}{=}$` for $\stackrel{(1)}{=}$, or `\tag{1}`.

Comment: Surely the top line (and further $I$'s) should read $$I= \int \operatorname{sech}x dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $I_1=2\arctan(e^x), I_2=\arcsin(\mathrm{sech}(x)), I_3=\arctan(\sinh(x))$.
Then 
$$I_1 = I_3+\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and (with Maple's conventions for principal value of $\arcsin$)
$$
I_2 = I_1\quad\text{for } x \le 0
\\
I_2 = \pi - I_1 \quad\text{for } x > 0
$$
So I conclude $I_1$ and $I_3$ are correct, and $I_2$ is correct up to sign.